# SonarQube: how to revert the automatic author assignment made based on the SCM info

Tags: sonarqube

The property **sonar.scm.enabled** was enabled by default and during the analysis a lot of issues were assigned to the same author, though this was not the real author of those issues. 
This is because that git user was the responsible to migrate the code from a previous version control.

I want to know if is there any way to unassign all issues assigned to a specific author, using some kind of bulk change or a specific configuration during an analysis.

Sonar version: 5.1.2

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned your version of the SonarQube platform, so I'll assume 5.1.*.

In the Issues page, do an Assignee search, and then use Bulk Change to re/un-assign the results.

Comment: Yes, is the 5.1.2 version. I already found that option, but here I can only assign, no unassign.

Comment: Ok, it seems it's possible to unassign. I don't know why but the last time I checked the only option I had was "Assigned to me". No I have the option "Not assigned" which I assume is the option I need. Thx

Comment: It seems sometimes the option "Not assigned" is not available, but I couldn't figure out why...

Comment: While it's possible to unassign the assignee, I also want to remove the author info, which was retrieved from the SCM, because the real author is not the one from the SCM (the reason is that this was migrated from another SCM). Is this possible?

Comment: Sorry, it's not possible to reassess blame.